# Do iOS apps share frameworks?

Tags: ios

If several apps are installed on the same device which use the same framework, are multiple copies of the framework code stored on the device or do all apps share them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's a system-provided framework, then every app uses the shared system copy of the framework. If it's a framework you downloaded and added to your project, then your app uses that private copy. (The same is true for OS X apps and frameworks).

(Note that non-system iOS frameworks must be static, so they wouldn't be shareable between apps anyway. But, this answer would hold true even if dynamic library frameworks were possible, as is the case on OS X).

Comment: Does this answer still hold true now that non-system Swift iOS frameworks are  dynamic libraries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094661/swift-ios-custom-framework-conflicts/36095335?noredirect=1#comment59850197_36095335

Comment: OK. I think it does. So then, [can't I carelessly change my framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116426/cant-i-carelessly-change-my-framework)?

Answer (score 1):

System frameworks are "shared" I guess you could say. More so, apps are **linked** to the frameworks on the system.